# Adobe Flash shape tween adding random anchor points

Tags: flash, animation, shapes, symbols, anchorpoint

I'm trying to animate a simple logo in Flash Professional CC, using lines and a shape tween (just like I've seen people animate stick figures).

[image]

Even with my symbol changing only very slightly and adding many keyframes and shape hints, the shape tween seems to add many random anchor points (honestly, a hundred) between keyframes, disfiguring my logo.

[image]

Is there a way to disable the automatic creation of new anchor points?
Or is there a better way to approach simple animation?